# Linpus 9.4 (based on Fedora) change locale

Tags: fedora, locale, language

I got old Linpus Linux 9.4 from 2007 into my hands and I just want to change locale. `locale -a` lists the locale I want, but there is no locale.conf in /etc/ or anywhere else. The distro should be based on that time Fedora (cca 8), does anyone remember how to change locale on Fedora 7/8?

Linpus is based on old Xfce 4.4.2, but language switch in the main panel is missing. Also I tried to upload new updated Linux distro, but failed to boot from USB on the old machine unfortunately.